# Is there a way to make inline-block elements behave like table cells?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mimic an HTML table with css classes, but the last "cell" element always gets pushed to the next line.

The way I am currently getting around this is to decrease the width of the last element by a few percent, so that the total width of the elements adds up to ~ 97%. This protects the last element from being pushed to the next line, but it doesn't look as nice because there's unused space at the end.

Is there a way to get the table cells to line up nicely and use 100% of the containing width?

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%">Last Name</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%">First Name</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width:20%">Age</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be emulating the table structure using `table` styles in the same way that would be applied to a typical html `table` structure; so the containing parent element with the class `.table` should be `display: table`, the containing element with the class `.row` should be `display: table-row`, the nested children elements with the class `.cell` should be `display: table-cell`, etc. Although, if you need a table structure, why aren't you just using `table` to begin with?

Comment: In this context, a "row" is a really a header that can be expanded to display more details about that particular item. So it isn't a traditional tabular data presentation. Otherwise, what you suggest would work perfectly.

Comment: Are the other answers not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known "problem" with `display:inline-block;`

One solution is to comment the "space" between your divs.
Other solutions exist, you should have a look at this question: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%">Last Name</div><!--
    --><div class="cell" style="width:40%">First Name</div><!--
    --><div class="cell" style="width:20%">Age</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hvae 2 solutions.

The first solution is that

```css
.row{
  font-size: 0;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%">Last Name</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width:40%">First Name</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width:20%">Age</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just set `font-size:0` at parent `div`.

But I don't like this solution.

**The second solution is that**

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
.cell {
  /* display: inline-block; It's not require */
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="cell" style="width:40%">Last Name</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:40%">First Name</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width:20%">Age</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I recommend you `display:flex`.

If you want to learn about `flex`, you can find it in Google easily.

Comment: I don't think flex items need display inline-block.

Comment: @eramit2010 I think it's not important thing. I just give way to solve.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst I applaud you for using semantically correct markup, if you are displaying tabular type data, then this should be using a table.